# package org.hibernate.cfg is accessible from more than one module error:

Tags: hibernate

I am starting to hibernate today and I configure the other setting and create a class Employee and I want to test and I created another class Test with the main method but when I try to create an object of Annotation configuration the import statement on the header is an error the error says "package org.hibernate.cfg is accessible from more than one module error:"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you added the associated hibernate jar files to the module path. All you need to do is remove them from the module path but re-add them to the Classpath.

Assuming you're using eclipse: just right click on the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> click on "Modulepath" (you should see it next to a little up-and-down arrow) -> remove hibernate jar files or simply remove all jar files added from "lib" folder -> click on "Classpath" which should be underneath the "Modulepath" and then add all jar files you just removed.

Then your problem should be solved. :)